# Glimpse.AspNet.pdb not loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdb-files, glimpse

I have an MVC application which uses Glimpse and for the last couple days I haven't been able to solve it. It throws a null reference at the start of each run.[image]

I have tried clearing caches, reinstalling the nuget packages, and tried clearing out the local repo and pulling it down again.

The program builds and works fine with Glimpse working on others environments and on mine it works if I continue past the error but leaving it as is is feels concerning.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Make sure that the **Enable Just My Code** option is enabled and the **Enable .NET Framework source stepping** deactivated:
   [image]

Comment: glimpse works ?not dead project ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the interventions above and still no joy. Our app was built on a framework that uses glimpse, but it's an old product. I checked the 'Except when thrown from Glimpse.aspnet.dll' checkbox, clicked run, clicked stop, just to make sure it saves, and then clicked run again and life is good.

[image: Override error for glimpse.aspnet.pdb]

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions on [vbforum](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?858051-RESOLVED-Cannot-find-or-open-the-PDB-file) did not help.
Uninstall and install of VS 2019 worked partly due to enabled option "Enable Just My Code" placed in Debugging -> General otherwise error is still present.